# onConfigurationChanged never fires

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to stop `Activity` recreation due to device orientation change by setting `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to my `Activity` and listening for orientation change by overriding `onConfigurationChanged` method. I am testing it on Nexus 5, but it is not working in Android L device because `onConfigurationChanged` never fires. It just sticks to portrait mode, and does not rotate.

Is it a bug in Android L, am I doing something incorrectly, or they have introduced some other way to do this?

Comment: Sticks to portrait? Does it not rotate at all?

Comment: It does not rotate..

Comment: Are you usjng android:screenOrientation in your manifest? If so, remove it. This might be silly but, do you have auto rotation enabled?

Comment: That was so silly.. From my side.. auto rotate was disabled.. Thank you so much.. And sorry for asking such silly question.. I guess I have to delete this question

Comment: You dont have to delete it, let it be a reference for others who encounter this. P.s this has happened to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you usjng android:screenOrientation in your manifest? If so, remove it. This might be silly but, do you have auto rotation enabled?

Comment: Auto rotaion was disabled.. I will not delete this question even though it is silly because as you said it will be helpful for someone if they stuck with same problem

Answer (score 0):

Aashir is correct! With this, add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize" to your activity in menifest.xml